# Cannot convert a value of type List to type Text

Tags: sharepoint, google-cloud-dataflow, dataverse

Trying to run a Dataflow to move a Sharepoint list in to Dataverse. The column is a multi select field that i'm trying to load to a multi line text field. Each time this is run I get an error, We cannot convert a value of type List to type Text.

I have also seen this on the list's modified by and created by fields. Not sure to get around this.

pulling this in to a Power Automate Flow I am seeing additional items around modified by and created by to pull the display name.

For the Multi select field I see, [{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":0,"Value":"ME"},{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":1,"Value":"NY"},{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":19,"Value":"FL"}]